# okio.Base64.encode ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException why is that even happening?

Tags: android, caching, base64, okhttp, crash-reports

I noticed such exception in fabric, which is occurring rarely but with every build, 3-5 crashes every week on 2-3 users (from ~500 DAU)
I didn't found any information about such crashes, does anyone knows what causes them?

I've found only one question about such issue but it was deleted as "duplicate" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45868217/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-trying-to-cache-certificate-list-in-okhttp3

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
length=1305; index=1953974520

okio.Base64.encode (Base64.java:137)
okio.Base64.encode (Base64.java:125)
okio.ByteString.base64 (ByteString.java:105)
okhttp3.Cache$Entry.writeCertList (Cache.java:686)
okhttp3.Cache$Entry.writeTo (Cache.java:645)
okhttp3.Cache.put (Cache.java:249)
okhttp3.Cache.access$000 (Cache.java:136)
okhttp3.Cache$1.put (Cache.java:148)
okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.maybeCache (CacheInterceptor.java:173)
okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept (CacheInterceptor.java:143)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
```

**UPDATE:**

https://github.com/square/okio/issues/325 Okio ticket for this issue
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69364976 Google ticket for this issue

**UPDATE 2:**
was fixed in Android Studio 3.1 Canary 6 Build

Comment: If you downvote question - at least write why.

Comment: `I noticed such exception`. If you talk about an exception then at least mention which one.

Comment: It is already issued here: https://github.com/square/okio/issues/325

Comment: @greenapps exception is printed in question

Comment: @JanMuller thank you, it is issued indeed just yesterday, I've searched it 2 days ago, so there was no topic at the moment. Can you write it as the answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably bug in VM at particular devices starting from 8 of November only on Android 5.1.

We have found out that the problem is caused by using dex compiler D8. The solution is to disable it in gradle.properties by this line: android.enableD8=false

Ticket was already created here

[Okio issue tracker](https://github.com/square/okio/issues/325)

It is affecting almost all low cost phones excluding Samsung devices

Answer (score 2):

It’s a bug in either the VM or the infrastructure around the VM (the CPU?, the memory?). There’s no other way a value `i`, that loops between 0 and an array’s length, can go out of bounds like this.